# How to convert one character from a string to a char in delphi

Tags: string, delphi, char, delphi-xe2, case

I have a string, from which I want to extract one character that is needed to be used in a `Case` statement. The thing is the `Case` only takes `Char` values and not string values. So how do I convert a single string character to a char?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the string as a character array (1-based), and use the index of the character you want to use in the `case` statement. For instance, if you want to use the first character:

```
case MyString[1] Of
// ...
end;
```

NB make sure you check the the string is of at least that length before you use the subscript, or you'll get an access violation.

Comment: Hands up if you have a function in your personal library of code with a signature like the following: `function StrToChar(const S: string; Index: Integer = 1; Default: Char = ' '): Char;`

Comment: Nice edit, I do C# and Delphi, and always end up with a mental block on zero and 1 based, have to check every time I switch

Comment: Shortest is this: `c := Copy(s + ' ', 1, 1)[1];`

Answer (score 3):

Since `string` became 0-based on [mobile platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi)), there is also an always-safe way to get a char from single-character string.

```
myString[Low(myString)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since delphi became cross-platform I would use 0-based string access using `TStringHelper` class out of unit `System.SysUtils`:

```
case MyString.Chars(0) Of
// ...
end;
```